# Flutter webapp crashes when trying to show asset image

Tags: flutter, web-applications, firebase-hosting

I am new to developing webapps using Flutter. I have created a basic portfolio web app, and deployed it using Firebase Hosting.

The app is working fine till it has to render an image from the assets folder on the screen. As soon as it tries to render the image, the screen goes white.

What can I do to fix this problem?